# My Canvas Size Showing Different when I am trying to change the units

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard, file-size, canvas

I am very new to photoshop I am facing a problem that is whenever I am trying to change my canvas size it is showing some improper size instead showing the original.

[image: Image1]

> as per this 210 mm = 2480 pixels
> But in actual 1 mm = 3.7795 pixel

[image: Image2]

**So my canvas size should be 210 x 3.7795 = 793.7007874 Pixel**

So why it is showing this size?

Answer (score 4):

A pixel has **no size**.... a pixel is **not** a physical measurement. **That unit converter is bogus.** It's not possible to tell you the size of a lone pixel in relation to some physical dimension. In addition, you **can't** reproduce a 7th of a pixel. Pixel counts are always *whole* integers.

Trust Photoshop.

2480px ÷ 300ppi = 8.2666667" = 210mm
3508px ÷ 300ppi = 11.6933333" = 297mm

Total pixels divided by resolution provides the physical measurement for output. Without the resolution (ppi, i.e. pixel density) there's *no way* any "unit converter" can determine how large or small a single pixel may be.

Comment: Dear @Scott I have tried the same on my friends laptop, and the pixels were correct after changing the units.

Comment: I have no clue what that means. Your Photoshop screenshot in the question is correct. Please *read* this answer again, or more carefully. The "3.7795" number is **fake** and not an actual value you should be using anywhere.

Comment: **Any** time you see a decimal place for a pixel -- the number is simply **false**. Pixels *never* have decimal places. 1 millimeter **DOES NOT** equal 3.777 pixels

Comment: I think the confusion arises in that, for a given screen of a given size & resolution, you can work out the 'size' [centre to centre] of the pixels. This will only translate if two users have the same sized screen, at the same resolution, & same display magnifier size. The unit converter has made assumptions & isn't telling us which [aside from not being able to spilt a pixel].

Answer (score 1):

I would take a step back, forget the conversion and reconsider the purpose of the document:

- if this is a web document, start in pixels (eg. you don't need mm's for a web banner)
- if this is a print document, start in mm's (eg. no paper in this world is sold in pixel sizes)
- if this is a print AND web document, start in mm's and forget about the pixel conversion (any device opening a PNG, JPG or PDF will probably just fit the artwork to the screen, regardless of pixel count)

This is also why Photoshop clearly separates between PRINT and WEB in the NEW DOCUMENT window. In the PRINT tab you get print units by default (inches, cm, etc), and in the WEB tab you get pixels by default.

[image]

[image]